# How to compare data sets and combine based on matching ids in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I know it is very easy to do in databases, but how to do it in Excel?

I tried using **=vlook(indexcolumn,match(lookupvale,lookuparray,0))** next to ID column in Master set but then when I sort the values in data set gets jumbled and becomes hard. Challenge is there are thousands of records I will be combining.

*I have Master and Data Set tables. Need "Desired Output".*
[image: Pleasee see the image below]

Comment: a simple way in vba is to do a loop in a loop, but it is quite inefficient. I would put the "Data Set" in a scripting.dictionary, then loop over the Master and look for matches using .exists.

Comment: For me it's working fine even if I sort the data in Data Set. How is your data located?

Comment: Everything in 'Desired Output' can be found using `VLOOKUP` formulas into the other two tables. What problem are you having with `VLOOKUP` ?